# What is the use of creating a class inside interface and interface inside class

Tags: java, class, interface

I want to know what is the need of placing a class inside interface and an interface inside class?

```
class A {
   interface B {}
}

interface D {
   class E {}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400828/inner-class-within-interface

Answer (score 22):

This i am copying and pasting from some link (i earlier did and sharing with you)
May be that can help you a bit.

1)

```
interface employee{
class Role{
      public String rolename;
      public int roleId;
 }
Role getRole();
// other methods
 }
```

In the above interface you are binding the Role type strongly to the employee interface(employee.Role).
2)     With a static class inside an interface you have the possibility to shorten a common programming fragment: Checking if an object is an instance of an interface, and if so calling a method of this interface. Look at this example:

```
  public interface Printable {
    void print();

    public static class Caller {
        public static void print(Object mightBePrintable) {
                if (mightBePrintable instanceof Printable) {
                        ((Printable) mightBePrintable).print();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of doing this:

```
  void genericPrintMethod(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Printable) {
        ((Printable) obj).print();
    }
}
```

You can write:

```
   void genericPrintMethod(Object obj) {
         Printable.Caller.print(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Organization.

Specifying a class inside an interface ties that class directly to that interface - clients which use that interface will have access to that class and all the functionality that it provides.

I've seen the pattern of a class inside an interface really only in Java 1.4 and lower to provide an enumerated type to go along with the interface - since the interface could only use the class, and the class can be protected, clients that use the interface could only accept the instances of the class defined in the interface as the enumerated values.  That's just the only example I can come up with - I'm sure others exist, but it's rare that I see a class inside of an interface used.

For the flipped case, it's still organization.  Specifying an interface inside of a class signifies that only that class should use the interface.  That other classes and interfaces can still use that interface, depending on its access level, is not the point - the organization documents the intent of the interface - to be used only in the class that contains it.

If it is useful outside of that class, it should be moved appropriately to its own type.  So, both of these uses are rare, but their use is primarily to organize the code and document its intent directly via Java syntax.

Comment: I think that an example was given in the http://stackoverflow.com/a/10481539/1083704

Answer (score 3):

If functionality of a class is closely associated with an interface and we are not going to use that class anywhere then we can define a class inside an interface.

```
package PracticeTest;

public interface VehicleService {
   public void repair(Vehicle v);
   public class Vehicle{
      String vehicleModel;
      String vehicleNumber;
      public Vehicle(String vehicleModel, String vehicleNumber) {
      super();
      this.vehicleModel = vehicleModel;
      this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
      }

   }
}
```

In above case vehicle class is available for VehicleService and we are not using it anywhere else.

2. To provide default implementation of an interface we can define a class inside an interface

**Interface**

```
package PracticeTest;

public interface VehicleService {
public void repair();
public class DefaultVehicle implements VehicleService{

    @Override
    public void repair() {          
        System.out.println(" Default Repair");
    }
}
```

**Implementation Class**

```
 package PracticeTest;
 public class busRepair implements VehicleService{

   @Override
   public void repair() {
       System.out.println(" Bus Repair");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        busRepair b = new busRepair();
        b.repair();
        DefaultVehicle d = new DefaultVehicle();
        d.repair();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If any class functionality is closely associate with any interface in that situation we declare a class inside an interface.

Some time it is also useful to provide default implementation of abstract method inside interface.

Answer (score 0):

creating class inside interface allow programmer to have restrictions on class i.e., that inner class is accessible only if we implement that interface.

Comment: No its not true, we can access inner classes without implementing as well - `InterfaceName.ClassName a= new InterfaceName.ClassName ();a.print(10);`