# Why is it allowed to declare a static class inside an interface?

Tags: java, oop, static

```
public interface I1
{
static class Test{}
}
```

Why Java allow class written in  Interface?

is it good idea to write static class in interface?
any example where we can use it effectively?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932499/what-is-the-use-of-creating-a-class-inside-interface-and-interface-inside-class