# Classes inside interface

Tags: java

I was trying to develop an interface and that interface will contain static class

```
class C1 {

    static interface I // A static interface or class can contain static members.Static members can be
    //accessed without instantiating the particular class
    {

        static class C2 {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        C1.I.C2 ob1 = new C1.I.C2();
        System.out.println("object created");
    }
}
```

But my query is that can interface contain classes which are not static and if yes , then how their object would be created , please advise. Thanks

Comment: check this plz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625/why-would-a-static-inner-interface-be-used-in-java

Comment: @assylias..I am still doing R&D on this...!!

Comment: Possible duplicate [inner class within Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400828/1048330)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can an interface contain classes?

Yes.  For example, in

```
interface Widget {
  static class Factory {
    static Widget create() { return new Widget() {}; }
  }
}
```

the inner class can be accessed as

```
Widget w = Widget.Factory.create();
```

so to refer to the inner class you can just use the interface name then a dot then the inner class name

```
import my.pkg.MyInterface;

...

  MyInterface.InnerClass ic = new MyInterface.InnerClass();
```