# How to implement nested non-static classes in interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

Having this class

```
public abstract class Mother{
  public class Embryo{
    public void ecluse(){
      bear(this);
    }
  }
  abstract void bear(Embryo e);
}
```

i can create a Instance of Embryo only if i have a instance of Mother:

```
new Mother(){...}.new Embryo().ecluse();
```

Question:

- How to define Mother as an interface?

Comment: Not completly unrelated but also not really answering your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400828/inner-class-within-interface

Comment: Could you provide some information on how you plan to use this interface/class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested class `Embryo` is implicitly `static` in an `interface`.

As such, it does not have access to the virtually invokable method `bear`, which would pertain to instances of your `Mother` interface.

Therefore:

- Either you declare `Mother` as `interface`, then your `Embryo`'s `ecluse` method cannot virtually invoke `bear` because it's statically-scoped
- Or, you keep `Mother` as an `abstract class`, but require an instance of a `Mother` (anonymous or a child class' instance) in order to get an instance of `Embryo` (but `Embryo` is instance-scoped unless specified otherwise, and can invoke `bear` virtually)

**Self-contained example**

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public interface MotherI {
        // this is static!
        public class Embryo {
            public void ecluse() {
                // NOPE, static context, can't access instance context
                // bear(this);
            }
        }
        // implicitly public abstract
        void bear(Embryo e);
    }

    public abstract class MotherA {
        public class Embryo {
            public void ecluse() {
                // ok, within instance context
                bear(this);
            }
        }

        public abstract void bear(Embryo e);
    }

    // instance initializer of Main
    {
        // Idiom for initializing static nested class
        MotherI.Embryo e = new MotherI.Embryo();
        /*
         *  Idiom for initializing instance nested class
         *  Note I also need a new instance of `Main` here,
         *  since I'm in a static context.
         *  Also note anonymous Mother here.
         */
        MotherA.Embryo ee = new MotherA() {public void bear(Embryo e) {/*TODO*/}}
           .new Embryo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither an `abstract class` nor an `interface` can be intstanticated without a class who is implementing `Mother`, you need another class anyway! So why does it care? Instances of Embryo are only available via a instance of the outer class `Mother`, if its a interface or an abstract class,

Comment: Not exactly for the last part. Let me give you an example.

Comment: I understand the first sentence compleatly. Why is it so?

Comment: i did not need the codeexample, i already got what you mean, but why is it so?

Comment: @PeterRader I think this is just part of the Java language specifications, but I'm having trouble finding an explicit reference. All member of `interface`s are `static public final` implicitly. However nested `class`es of `interfaces` are only `public static` but not `final`, as they can be extended.