# Inner class within Interface in C#

Tags: c#

The following question shows how to implement an interface that contains a class in java:

[inner class within Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400828/inner-class-within-interface)

The code in Java is:

```java
public interface A {
    class B {
    }
}
```

I was hoping the same thing was possible in C#, though I haven't yet been able to get anything working.

For reference, I have a class which makes lookups of key values, but the keys aren't named in a way that makes them easy to understand. I'd like to have a compile time lookup for keys, so the interface would be something like:

```cs
interface Lookup {
    class Keys {
        string SomeKey() => "0"
    }
}
```

Which means I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to have an interface containing a class?
2. Is there a better way of having a lookup between two strings (or any other values) that I can reference reliably at compile time?

Comment: For your second question _"Is there a better way of having a lookup between two strings"_ I'd suggest to take a look at the [`Dictionary<,>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) of the .NET Framework. Sounds like that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: 1-it is not possible. 2-why do not you use a Dictionary<string, string>?

Comment: @bassfader A dictionary would indeed have most of the functionality I'm looking for, but I'd prefer to restrict the selection of keys to a known range at compile time

Comment: @OliverRadini Then have you considered to simply use a custom `enum` type as key for your dictionary?

Comment: @bassfader I'm not sure whether that'd ensure that all the keys of the `enum` exist and are available, though?

Comment: why don't you just have a list of constants?  (see my answer)

Comment: Judging by your answers, you might have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @nkr indeed, I did suspect this may be the case and added the second part of the question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put no you can't have a class inside an interface.

From your comments you are talking about having a restricted list of available strings for the keys so I'm wondering if you are in fact not looking for a string/string lookup but just want a convenient way of referencing a list of fixed strings.  So a class with constants is all you need:

```
public static class Strings 
{
    public const string AString = "A";
    public const string BString = "B";
    public const string CString = "C";
}
```

Accessed like this:

```
var s = Strings.AString;
```

Comment: A list of constants is sounding like the closest thing to what I'm looking for at the moment, I suppose the data structure is more similar to an `enum`, except with strings as values; the advantage being that I can group all of these values. They could be defined separately, but then the interface has a new member for every key which is required, rather than a single data structure which holds all the keys

Comment: Yes it is sort of like an enum with strings.  I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have an class within an interface in C#. Interfaces are very simple in C#, and only provide a contract of functionality.

If you want to have a mapping between two strings, a `Dictionary<string, string>` may be of use to you.

Comment: I'm confused because the answers here aren't that old, but they all agree that it's not possible - but I'm looking right at it in my IDE right now.

Comment: @RaphaelSchmitz - I am also confused... This library makes heavy use of Classes within an Interface, I have ran the code locally, even added features to the code, it 100% works with nested classes WITHIN an interface: https://github.com/Singulink/Singulink.IO.FileSystem

Answer (score 2):

An interface can't itself have any instance data. It's implementation however can have any instance data it requires.

For example, a random example that might give you some insight:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string Value { get; set; }
    SomeClass SomeClass { get; set;}
}

public class SomeInterfaceImplementation : ISomeInterface
{
    public SomeInterfaceImplementation()
    {
        SomeClass = new SomeClass()
        {
            Key = "ABC"
        };
    }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var example = new SomeInterfaceImplementation()
        {
            Value = "A value",
        } as ISomeInterface;
        Console.WriteLine($"{example.SomeClass.Key} has value '{example.Value}'");
    }
}
```

In the example, the default constructor "generates" a key of ABC. We could implement this any way your logic requires. But you also have a contract that requires "SomeClass" and it's key is present.

Anywhere you want to use the contract, just accept the Interface and **not** an implementation class.

Additionally, feel free to [play with the fiddle:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RHqGr)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers under this question are no longer true.
Since C# 8.0, when [default interface methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.md) were added, it is possible for an interface to have member declaration that declare for example nested type.
The following code is correct for C# 8.0:

```
public interface IA
{
    class B
    {
    }
}
```