# Using Scala traits with implemented methods in Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I guess it is not possible to invoke methods implemented in Scala traits from Java, or is there a way?

Suppose I have in Scala:

```
trait Trait {
  def bar = {}
}
```

and in Java if I use it as

```
class Foo implements Trait {
}
```

Java complains that `Trait is not abstract and does not override abstract method bar() in Trait`

Comment: Is this an error? Shouldn't the line look like "Java complains that **Foo** is not abstract and does not override abstract method bar() in Trait" ?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

### Answer

From Java perspective `Trait.scala` is compiled into `Trait` **interface**. Hence implementing `Trait` in Java is interpreted as implementing an interface - which makes your error messages obvious. Short answer: you can't take advantage of trait implementations in Java, because this would enable multiple inheritance in Java (!)

#### How is it implemented in Scala?

Long answer: so how does it work in Scala? Looking at the generated bytecode/classes one can find the following code:

```
interface Trait {
    void bar();
}

abstract class Trait$class {
    public static void bar(Trait thiz) {/*trait implementation*/}
}

class Foo implements Trait {
    public void bar() {
        Trait$class.bar(this);  //works because `this` implements Trait
    }
}
```

- `Trait` is an interface
- abstract `Trait$class` (do not confuse with `Trait.class`) class is created transparently, which technically does **not** implement `Trait` interface. However it does have a `static bar()` method taking `Trait` instance as argument (sort of `this`)
- `Foo` implements `Trait` interface
- `scalac` automatically implements `Trait` methods by delegating to `Trait$class`. This essentially means calling `Trait$class.bar(this)`.

Note that `Trait$class` is neither a member of `Foo`, nor does `Foo` extend it. It simply delegates to it by passing `this`.

### Mixing in multiple traits

To continue the digression on how Scala works... That being said it is easy to imagine how mixing in multiple traits works underneath:

```
trait Trait1 {def ping(){}};
trait Trait2 {def pong(){}};
class Foo extends Trait1 with Trait2
```

translates to:

```
class Foo implements Trait1, Trait2 {
  public void ping() {
    Trait1$class.ping(this);    //works because `this` implements Trait1
  }

  public void pong() {
    Trait2$class.pong(this);    //works because `this` implements Trait2
  }
}
```

### Multiple traits overriding same method

Now it's easy to imagine how mixing in multiple traits overriding same method:

```
trait Trait {def bar(){}};
trait Trait1 extends Trait {override def bar(){}};
trait Trait2 extends Trait {override def bar(){}};
```

Again `Trait1` and `Trait2` will become interfaces extending `Trait`. Now if `Trait2` comes last when defining `Foo`:

```
class Foo extends Trait1 with Trait2
```

you'll get:

```
class Foo implements Trait1, Trait2 {
    public void bar() {
        Trait2$class.bar(this); //works because `this` implements Trait2
    }
}
```

However switching `Trait1` and `Trait2` (making `Trait1` to be last) will result in:

```
class Foo implements Trait2, Trait1 {
    public void bar() {
        Trait1$class.bar(this); //works because `this` implements Trait1
    }
}
```

### Stackable modifications

Now consider how traits as stackable modifications work. Imagine having a really useful class Foo:

```
class Foo {
  def bar = "Foo"
}
```

which you want to enrich with some new functionality using traits:

```
trait Trait1 extends Foo {
  abstract override def bar = super.bar + ", Trait1"
}

trait Trait2 extends Foo {
  abstract override def bar = super.bar + ", Trait2"
}
```

Here is the new 'Foo' on steroids:

```
class FooOnSteroids extends Foo with Trait1 with Trait2
```

It translates to:

#### Trait1

```
interface Trait1 {
  String Trait1$$super$bar();
  String bar();
}
abstract class Trait1$class {
  public static String bar(Trait1 thiz) {
    // interface call Trait1$$super$bar() is possible
    // since FooOnSteroids implements Trait1 (see below)
    return thiz.Trait1$$super$bar() + ", Trait1";
  }
}
```

#### Trait2

```
public interface Trait2 {
  String Trait2$$super$bar();
  String bar();
}
public abstract class Trait2$class {
  public static String bar(Trait2 thiz) {
    // interface call Trait2$$super$bar() is possible
    // since FooOnSteroids implements Trait2 (see below)
    return thiz.Trait2$$super$bar() + ", Trait2";
  }
}
```

#### FooOnSteroids

```
class FooOnSteroids extends Foo implements Trait1, Trait2 {
  public final String Trait1$$super$bar() {
    // call superclass 'bar' method version
    return Foo.bar();
  }

  public final String Trait2$$super$bar() {
    return Trait1$class.bar(this);
  }

  public String bar() {
    return Trait2$class.bar(this);
  }      
}
```

So the whole stack invocations are as follows:

- 'bar' method on FooOnSteroids instance (entry point);
- Trait2$class's 'bar' static method passing this as argument and returning a concatenation of 'Trait2$$super$bar()' method call and string ", Trait2";
- 'Trait2$$super$bar()' on FooOnSteroids instance which calls ...
- Trait1$class's 'bar' static method passing this as argument and returning a concatenation of 'Trait1$$super$bar()' method call and string ", Trait1";
- 'Trait1$$super$bar' on FooOnSteroids instance which calls ...
- original Foo's 'bar' method

And the result is "Foo, Trait1, Trait2".

### Conclusion

If you've managed to read everything, an answer to the original question is in the first four lines...

Comment: Well... it is missing how `abstract override` works, but it's pretty good otherwise. :-)

Comment: Thanks! And a typo: You wrote `class Foo implements Trait1, Trait2` again when you intended to switch Trait1 and Trait2.

Comment: @KajMagnus: this part was added by *Tvaroh*, maybe he can fix it?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Sorry I misread the answer. I think it's correct as is. (Didn't notice that the relevant code snippet is actually Java code not Scala code).

Comment: +1 As a compiler developer (and enthusiast), this information was really helpful. Now I don't need to reverse-engineer it myself. Thanks a lot! :3

Comment: This is very good answer, but I  see it was answered in 2011, before Java 8 that supports [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). What's the implementation after Java 8?

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed not abstract since `bar` is returning an empty `Unit` (a kind of NOP). Try:

```
trait Trait {
  def bar: Unit
}
```

Then `bar` will be a Java abstract method returning `void`.

Comment: That is my question. If I have a complex method implemented in `bar` of `Trait`, I would like to reuse it in a Java class, as I can do in Scala. But I guess this is not possible. The only fix seems to be to convert Trait into an abstract class.

Comment: Yes. You should make it an abstract class. Or even better, keep it as a trait, but add an abstract class which just extends it (to have a Java binding). Then you can extend the trait from Scala or inherit from the abstract class from Java.

Comment: Yes, though this will eat up the only available spot for Java abstract classes.

Comment: Other solution is to use composition/aggregation. You could either use the generated static method (see Tomasz answer) or write an object suitable for nice Java interaction.