# Why declare a function this verbosely?

Tags: function, scala, anonymous-function

Going through some code, I came across the function

```
def sum(): Function2[Double, Double, Double] = 
  new Function2[Double, Double, Double] {
    def apply(t1: Double, t2: Double): Double = t1 + t2;
  }
```

How is this different than the much simpler declaration,

```
def sum(): Function2[Double, Double, Double] = _ + _
```

Is there any benefit to using the former approach?

Comment: btw, the bytecode for this two versions differs slightly -- both of those functions were put in distinct objects, compiled and decoded with javap. Former is compiled down to a single (plus unboxed version) method. Later is compiled to combination of different arguments (e.g. (double, int), (double, long) ... (long, double), (long, Object) ...  + curried methods + custom toString.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: `toString` is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @senia yes, it opts to default implementation, but [exists in bytecode](https://gist.github.com/lazyval/6e73be1a7f9bcd507b5d). The correct term should be *overriden* (if it is not it wouldn't be in bytecode, right?) with dummy redirection to [Function2.toString](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Function2.scala#L56).

Comment: @om-nom-nom: since `Function0` is trait there should be generated implementations with such redirections. The only difference is in case of lambda this implementation is in class `AbstractFunction2` and in case of `new Function2` this implementation is in anonymous class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Readability**

Verbose version is very clear for `Java`-developers. It looks almost like an anonymous class in Java. So it could be used to explain lambdas. This is the only advantage of the verbose version.

**REPL support**

There is a little difference in REPL, but it's not something useful:

```
scala> new Function2[Double, Double, Double] {
     |   def apply(t1: Double, t2: Double): Double = t1 + t2;
     | }
res0: java.lang.Object with (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>

scala> val sum: (Double, Double) => Double = _ + _
sum: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>
```

**Bytecode size**

In terms of `jvm` [trait is an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7637888/406435). When you create a class based on trait compiler generates methods with simple call of implementation from trait's companion object.

`FunctionN` traits up to two parameters are [`specialized`](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/9) on `Int`, `Long` and `Double` parameters, the result type parameter is additionally specialized on `Unit`, `Float` and `Boolean`. It means for `Function2` you'll get 54 addition `apply` methods (named like `apply$mcZDD$sp`).

With lambda version you are using abstract class `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2`. All methods are generated in this class. Overridden only those that are necessary. Class-file size for lambda (`ClassName$anonfun$1.class`) is **1012 bytes**. Less than 1kB.

In case of `new Function2` all methods are generated in anonymous class. Class-file size for anonymous class (`ClassName$anon$1.class`) is about **20 kB**.

For `Function3` (not specialized) difference is not so big: `1.1kB` vs `1.7kB`, but `FunctionN` with 0-2 arguments are the most common lambdas. Without `AbstractFunctionN` bytecode size would be huge.

Comment: So there is no difference between these alternatives? (Other than the readability factor of course)

Comment: @arshajii - Correct - there is no difference.

Comment: @senia - Huh?  They're both specialized.

Comment: @RexKerr: you are correct. Decompiled `Function2` version is frightening.

Comment: @RexKerr: could you please add your answer with an explanation why `AbstractFunctionN` classes are exists? I think it will be useful. It definitely will be better answer than mine.

Comment: @senia - I don't have time to write up an adequate answer.  The brief version is so that all the specialized forwarding methods don't have to be regenerated for each closure; they have a home in `AbstractFunctionN` and will be included by inheritance (saves bytecode).

Comment: @RexKerr: so it's only about bytecode size and compilation time, not about performance? I'll try to add it to my answer. Thank you.