# Intellij idea cannot resolve dollar containing classes

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, scala-java-interop

Here the problem: I have jar containing compiled scala code. In jar I see

Step.class
Step$class.class

which both are legal java classes.

However when I try to use Step$class in Intellij Idea java project it says: "Cannot resolve symbol Step$class". But code gets compiled with maven so I assume problem is in IDE.

Comment: Yep. BTW I use 11.0 intellij-idea.

Comment: In that case I would try 11.1.1 if you suspect its a bug.

Comment: Same for 11.1.1, it just ignores all $ containig classes.

Comment: I would log it as a bug to Jetbrains, they are usually fairly responsive even if you are using the free version. http://www.jetbrains.com/support/idea/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Scala traits can contain implementations, unlike Java interfaces. `scalac` compiles this into an interface and an implementation class:

```
  ~/code/scratch/20120505 cat trait.scala 
package test

trait T {
    def a = println("foo")
}
  ~/code/scratch/20120505 scalac210 -d . trait.scala 

  ~/code/scratch/20120505 javap -classpath . test/T
Compiled from "trait.scala"
public interface test.T extends scala.ScalaObject{
    public abstract void a();
}

  ~/code/scratch/20120505 javap -classpath . test/T\$class
Compiled from "trait.scala"
public abstract class test.T$class extends java.lang.Object{
    public static void a(test.T);
    public static void $init$(test.T);
}
```

The IntelliJ Scala plugin does not expose the implementation class to Java code. It's not really a good idea to use this directly, as you are relying on an implementation detail of the Scala compiler.

You should invoke the corresponding methods on a subclass of the trait. You'll have to write that in Scala, though.

More info: [How are Scala traits compiled into Java bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557303/how-are-scala-traits-compiled-into-java-bytecode)

Answer (score 0):

Ups, silly me, I've just invalidated all caches and re-imported jars, now it get resolved.