# Something similar to PHP traits in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a hierarchy of `SQL` query objects. My base class will be named Query. It will have methods like `Query.setTable("tableName")`.

Then I plan on having a `SelectiveQuery` object extend the Query object. This object will have methods like `SelectiveQuery.where("aColumn","=","123")`.

Then I plan on having `UpdateQuery`, `SelectQuery`, `DeleteQuery`, and `CountQuery` all extend `SelectiveQuery`. My dilemma arises when I try to figure out how to create the `InsertQuery` class. I want it to extend Query but not extend `SelectiveQuery`.

The kicker is that `InsertQuery` and `UpdateQuery` will share some of the same methods, such as `setValue("aColumn","aValue")`. I'd prefer to only maintain the methods `UpdateQuery` and `InsertQuery` have in common in one location. How do I tackle this? If I were programming in `PHP`. I think I'd use Traits to do this.

[image]

Comment: This is a design question here. You should change your diagram: make a base `ReadQuery` and `WriteQuery` inheriting `Query`, and add a `Criterion` API which you would use only on queries which need it. No need for traits ;)

Comment: so the `Criterion` API would be added to Query?

Comment: No, it would be another API; you'd add the criterion to the query before you build it. Something like `Query.newSelectQuery().onTable(table).usingCriterion(criterion).build()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java traits or mixins pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263121/java-traits-or-mixins-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

If InsertQuery and UpdateQuery have behaviour in common, can't you just create an abstract class that contains the common stuff and have InsertQuery and UpdateQuery extend it? The abstract class would extend SelectiveQuery so InsertQuery and UpdateQuery would inherit all of the other behaviour too.

However... Perhaps you could take a look at an ORM framework like Hibernate. No need to reinvent the wheel etc.

Comment: i don't want InsertQuery to extend SelectiveQuery. It doesn't make sense to have methods like InsertQuery.where("aColumn","=","123")

Comment: Ok, what about creating an interface that describes the methods that are common to both. Insert and Update would implement this interface. You can then create a service that contains implementations of these methods and Insert and Update can delegate to the service.

Comment: @David if methods don't make sense for a certain type of query, just make them do nothing! And BTW, you should have a look at the builder pattern

Comment: @fge Methods doing nothing is indicator of a poor design.

Comment: @kan disagree, in some case it is _very_ useful

Comment: @fge How is a method doing nothing could be useful??

Comment: @kan very simple: you have a DDL interface, you need certain DDL commands to be executed _before_ other queries are issued and some DDL commands _after_ other queries are issued. If you don't have empty methods, how do you make `.before()` "do nothing" if, for instance, you remove a column? Similarly, how do you make `.after()` do nothing if you add a column?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace inheritance by mixin, i.e. introduce another class such as Columns, InsertQuery and SelectiveQuery will have the class as a member, so the syntax will be `insertQuery.columns().setValue("aColumn", "aValue")`. Also, have a look here: [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/).

Comment: can be like this :  ColumnsQuery extends Query, and UpdateQuery, InsertQuery extends ColumnsQuery

Comment: @jospratik Not of course, the select, count and delete will have it then, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263311/8740349);

Is the object-purist stirring in you today?

Think you could do with a little *composite oriented programming?*

Then you, sir, are looking for [Apache Polygene](http://polygene.apache.org/) (formerly named Qi4J, then it renamed to Zest and/or Apache-Zest) ;)

**Update 2022;** It's discontinued currently, but useful anyway.