# does the concept of traits has similar meaning in both java and php?

Tags: php, traits

I am beginner in coding.I want to learn the concept of traits in php.I have a doubt that "does the concept of traits has similar meaning in both java and php"?If there are any differences what are they?

Comment: Probably too broad question to answer.....

Comment: It's perfectly covered in the docs

Comment: @AlexKarshin which docs ? java's or php's ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why use traits in PHP?

PHP provides single class inheritance not multiple so whenever your class needs to inherit functionality from multiple classes simple use traits.

```
trait Abc
{

     private static $_instance = null;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
      if (null === self::$_instance)
      {
        self::$_instance = new self();
      }

    return self::$_instance;
   }
}

class Test extends Example
{
  use Abc;
  ....
}
```

**In Java, it supports multiple inheritances.so whenever a class needs just extend multiple classes but at that time you may face one problem that is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126157/something-similar-to-php-traits-in-java).**

Comment: **Wrong,** Java does not support "multi" inheritance (but has "single" inheritance), and will not ever support C++'s multi-inheritance, because Java is a dead language (at least, it's dead as far as improvement is concerned, see my years old bug report: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48203021/8740349).